# How to check for real numbers in bash script programming

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement, conditional-statements, real-number

I am learning Bash script and I need to write a conditional statement which make sure that my input string is a real number.

**if [ *is not a real number* ]; then echo "not a real number"**

I have found something like this:

**if [ ! "$num" =~ ^-?[0-9]*(.[0-9]+)?$ ]**

It works but I cannot understand what it is. I paste this thing to GG to research but I cannot find anything explaining about this one clearly enough.

My question is: What is this and how does it work? Is there any different way to solve my problem?

Comment: Type `help [` in the shell, it will tell you what this is. Indirectly, you can use that to find out how the whole thing works.

Comment: It should be `[[ .. ]]` not `[ ... ]`. It is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) comparison

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap09.html

Comment: this question should probably be tagged [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex). Note that according to that description, questions asking "what does this regex do?" are off-topic for SO

Comment: btw, `.` in the regex shown should be `[.]` or `\.` (or for arcane bash reasons: `"."` or `'.'`)

Comment: The reason for the `[[ .. ]]` change is `[ .. ]` is a synonym for `test` (good old POSIX shell) -- it does not handle regular-expressions, Bash `[[ .. ]]` does.

Comment: Thank you for helping me everyone! I can understand this regular expression now. I really appreciate your help.